# I ran out of disk space on an ubuntu server. How can I know how the disk space is being used?

Tags: ubuntu, disk-space-utilization

I ran out of disk space on an ubuntu server. How can I know how the disk space is being used so I can clean up the disk / delete unnecessary files?

Answer (score 3):

- `df -h`: will tell you space usage of all mounted filesystems.
- `du -sh`: will tell you space usage of current directory.
- `du -h --max-depth=1`: will tell you space usage of each directory in current directory.

Comment: I like `du -sh ./*` to list the sizes of all the folders in the current directory.

Comment: I prefer:  df -PkH

Answer (score 2):

Listing files/folders by size in descending order;

```
du -sk * |sort -rn
```

In human readable sizes (GNU sort only);

```
du -sh * |sort -rh
```

Comment: answer could definitely use some explanation, it lists the files/folders by size in descending order, which I have to say is quite useful when trying to figure out what is hogging disk space. Doesn't list sizes in human readable form but still +1

Comment: Updated original answer with suggestions from @radman

Answer (score 2):

Try [NCurses Disk Usage](http://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu). It is pretty darn usable as an end-user tool (as opposed to something a programmer might use in a script).

Answer (score 0):

du is the command for the job as it will give you the disk usage.

Try to run `du -sh` at your root directory and then on the directories below.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

a graphical program that I like is `KDirStat`.  Someone else mentioned `ncdu` and it's nice.  `KDirStat` gives you one huge overview of your entire drive.

[KDirStat Homepage](http://kdirstat.sourceforge.net/)